# Does Angular Material have predetailed textboxes (ala bootstrap alert)

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Been playing around with angular material, and absolutely love it. But found one rather surprising thing, and almost certain I missed a page in the manual, or well, many pages including that one.

Thought I would add a warning text along the lines of "Thats not your password" for failed login. And from bootstrap I could easily do this with and alert box.

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Error:</span>
  Enter a valid email address
</div>
```

However, I can't find a similar set for angular material. Yes, there are dialog, and toasts, but I wanted something simpler.

And yes I could write my own class, but it feels like there should be some predefined class for it?

Answer (score 2):

I've been looking for such a feature too. The closest thing I can find is md-whiteframe. You can do an Angular Material type alert like this:

```
<div layout="row" layout-padding layout-wrap layout-fill>
    <div md-whiteframe="3" class="padded">
        Some text here
    </div>
</div>
```

However, the md-warn class doesn't work with this directive.

Answer (score 2):

as far i can see now there's no alert box in angular material like bootstrap

so i extract only alert css role from bootstrap

```
.alert {
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 5px; }

.alert-heading {
  color: inherit; }

.alert-link {
  font-weight: bold; }

.alert-dismissible {
  padding-right: 2rem; }
  .alert-dismissible .close {
    position: relative;
    top: -.125rem;
    right: -1rem;
    color: inherit; }

.alert-success {
  background-color: #dff0d8;
  border-color: #d0e9c6;
  color: #3c763d; }
  .alert-success hr {
    border-top-color: #c1e2b3; }
  .alert-success .alert-link {
    color: #2b542c; }

.alert-info {
  background-color: #d9edf7;
  border-color: #bcdff1;
  color: #31708f; }
  .alert-info hr {
    border-top-color: #a6d5ec; }
  .alert-info .alert-link {
    color: #245269; }

.alert-warning {
  background-color: #fcf8e3;
  border-color: #faf2cc;
  color: #8a6d3b; }
  .alert-warning hr {
    border-top-color: #f7ecb5; }
  .alert-warning .alert-link {
    color: #66512c; }

.alert-danger {
  background-color: #f2dede;
  border-color: #ebcccc;
  color: #a94442; }
  .alert-danger hr {
    border-top-color: #e4b9b9; }
  .alert-danger .alert-link {
    color: #843534; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes Angular Material has Dialog, you can use Alert Dialog, documentation [here](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog)

Add $mdDialog to your controller as dependency and customise below code.

```
    $scope.showAlert = function(ev) {
       $mdDialog.show(
           $mdDialog.alert()
             .parent(angular.element(document.querySelector('#popupContainer')))
             .clickOutsideToClose(true)
             .title('This is an alert title')
             .textContent('You can specify some description text in here.')
             .ariaLabel('Alert Dialog Demo')
             .ok('Got it!')
             .targetEvent(ev)
         );
       };
```

Call showAlert() from your html

```
   <md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="showAlert($event)"   flex="100"  flex-gt-md="auto">
      Alert Dialog
    </md-button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the trick, I was aware for Dialog, but I wanted something simpler. Literally like the code highlight used here at stack, but for alerts

Comment: This is the angular way for dialogs, you can skip few parts if you want , like title/clickOutsideToClose/ariaLabel. Or else you can just go with simple javascript alerts.

Comment: OK, will have to go the css route, getting connect flash into angular seems to much of a headache:)

Comment: He didn't want a dialog, he wanted something like Bootstrap's alerts: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/alerts/